# Why my sidebar is not sticking to the top everytime I scrolled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make my sidebar sticked at the top when everytime I scrolled but I dunno why it won't stick at the top.

Here's what I did and I expect it to sticked at the top when scrolled.

See my code below:

```
<section id="blog" class="blog">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8">...</div>

          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="sidebar">
              I'm trying to stick this column at the top when scrolled.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

CSS:
.blog .sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what that `row` class is doing. For example if it's a [flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container) that displays its child elements in a row like the example below then your sticky rule will work (with a minor adjustment).

```css
.row { display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
.main, .sidebar { padding: 0.25rem; border: 1px solid #555; border-radius: 5px; }
.main { height: 200vh; width: 80%; top: 10px; }
.sidebar { margin-left: auto; position: sticky; top: 10px; width: 80%; }
```

```html
<section id="blog" class="blog">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 main">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="sidebar">
          I'm trying to stick this column at the top when scrolled.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Wow! This is what I wanted to do. Thanks for the help Andy. <3

Answer (score 2):

The `<section>` needs to be `sticky` as well.

```css
.blog, .blog .sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="blog" class="blog">
  <div class="container" >

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8">...</div>

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="sidebar">
          I'm trying to stick this column at the top when scrolled.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<div style="height: 200vh">
    For testing...
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I will try this solution and will let you know if it work. Thank you. :)

Comment: It did'nt work.

Comment: @CarvelRussSilvano Did my sample code work for you?

Comment: https://carvelruss.com/img/sticked.png

Please check the image bro for your reference. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you don't have a parent element with position: relative. so to solve your problem you need to set:

```
.blog {
  position: relative;
}
```

and sidebar:

```
.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

hope it will help you. Let me know the result